# How to Count values of ManyToMany Field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to count all the `likes` in `Posts` models

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='likes')
```

What I am trying is

```
all_posts = Posts.objects.all()
j = all_posts.filter(user_profile=2).values('likes').count()
```

But this approach counts incorrectly when none of the Posts is liked(i.e. none of ManyToMany Field is selected by users) as it also counts `{'likes': None}` in QuerySet. for e.g When none of post is liked the queryset is `<QuerySet [{'likes': None}, {'likes': None}, {'likes': None}, {'likes': None}, {'likes': None}]>` and hence I get count as 5, which is not correct.

So, is there any way to count only selected values in `ManyToMany` Field or to exclude `{'likes': None}` while counting values of queryset.

Note : Once each post have atlest one `likes` then I get Correct count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use annotation and aggregation to achieve this.

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum

likes = (
        Posts.objects
        .filter(user_profile=2)  # filtering the post of specific user
        .annotate(likes_count=Count('likes'))  # counting likes on each post
        .aggregate(total_likes=Sum('likes_count'))  # Summing likes on each post to give total likes
    )
```

Comment: I think there is some problem with `likes_count` it is undefined when I run the above code

Comment: let me check once. which django version are you using?

Comment: I just tested this it's working as expected. Can you post the error that you are getting? Are you importing Count and Sum?

Comment: I am simply getting `NameError: name 'likes_count' is not defined`

Comment: Hey sorry, there was a typo in the code, I updated the answer can you check now.